# Ошибка отрисовки в cavnas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Пытаюсь анимировать пулю,плавно вылетающую при клике на пробел.Но с отрисовкой что-то не так.

[image: Баг отображения в canvas]

Код:

```js
function moveBullets(x,y){
            const start = performance.now(),
                  DEL = 50/3,
                  times = (timeForBulletToMove/1000) * 60,
                  bulletsRangeY = 100,
                  rangeForOneTime = bulletsRangeY/times;
            function f(timestamp){
                let INTERVAL = Math.round((timestamp - start)/DEL);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = '#1a1a1a';
                ctx.fillRect(x,y-(INTERVAL-1)*rangeForOneTime,30,40)
                ctx.fillStyle='yellowgreen';
                ctx.fillRect(
                x,
                y - INTERVAL * rangeForOneTime,
                30,40
                )
                if(INTERVAL === times) return;
                requestAnimationFrame(f)
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(f);
        }
```

Аргументы функции-это координаты левого верхнего угла пули.

Comment: лучше бы воспроизводимый  пример

Comment: но так на глазок - вы не очищаете канву перед отрисовкой следующего кадра

Comment: Благодарю,помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том,что я не сбрасывал канвас при отрисовке.

Comment: лучше добавьте кусочек кода, а то совсем на ответ не тянет и модераторы его удалят